# Reading csv file with large number of fields

Tags: php, csv

I have csv file with 104 fields, but I need only 4 fields to use in mysql database. each file has about a million rows.
could somebody tell me efficient way to do this? reading each line to array takes long time.
thanks

Comment: Would it go faster to read the file in with fgets? That way, you only read one line into memory at a time. I'm not sure how much faster it'd be, so I don't want to put it as an answer, but it may be worth a try. Otherwise, I'd say don't do this with php - use a bash script or similar to go through the files quickly, and then use php to store those values in your database.

Comment: some scripting would be fine. can you tell me steps to do it?

Comment: In its simplest form, you can just use sed and regular expressions, like this: `sed s/expression/replacement/flags myfile.csv > newfile.csv`

Comment: You will have to *read* the data while parsing the file somehow, but you can discard the unneeded data immediately. Unless *each line* is several MB, this should hardly make a difference in performance. Does it really take "a long time" to just *read one line*?

Comment: sorry, it take long time to process entire file, not a single line. simple excel macro can drop all unnecessary columns (100 out of 104) within second. I am looking for similar solution.

Comment: Joel Hinz, can I read part of line by fgets? 30 - 40 fields out of 104?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read every line in its entirety by definition. This is necessary to find the delimiter for the next record (i.e. the newline character). You only need to discard the data you have read that you don't need. E.g.:

```
$data    = array();
$fh      = fopen('data.csv', 'r');
$headers = fgetcsv($fh);

while ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $row    = array_combine($headers, $row);
    $data[] = array_intersect_key($row, array_flip(array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')));

    // alternatively, if you know the column index, something like:
    // $data[] = array($row[1], $row[45], $row[60]);
}
```

This only *retains* the columns foo, bar and baz and discards the rest. The *reading from file* (`fgetcsv`) is about as fast as it gets. If you need it any faster, you'll have to implement your own CSV tokenizer and parser which skips over the columns you don't need without even temporarily storing them in memory; how much of a performance boost this brings vs. development time necessary to implement this bug free is very debatable.

> simple excel macro can drop all unnecessary columns (100 out of 104)
>   within second. I am looking for similar solution.

That is because Excel, once a file is opened, has *all data in memory* and can act on it very quickly. For an accurate comparison you need to compare the time it takes to open the file in Excel + dropping of the columns, not *just* dropping the columns.